# Build helloworld GUI with QtCreator and CMAKE

Tags: cmake, qt5, qt-creator, qmake

1. I have build a hello world GUI with QtCreator using a qmake and .pro file.
2. I want to build the same hello world with QtCreator but with a CMAKE file
3. I followed [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-get-started.html) and was able to build the application successfully.
4. But when I run the program it does not show the main window GUI. In the application output it looks as following.

   ```
   21:52:36: Starting /home/mavbot/qtopen3d/build-guiCMake-Desktop_Qt_5_12_0_GCC_64bit-Default/guiCMake...
   ```
5. Where am I missing out..please help. My CMAKE file looks as follows:

   ```
   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1.0)

   project(guiCMake)

   set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
   set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
   set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

   if(CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS "3.7.0")
     set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
   endif()

   find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets Core REQUIRED)

   add_executable(guiCMake
    mainwindow.ui
    mainwindow.cpp
    main.cpp
   )

   target_link_libraries(guiCMake Qt5::Core Qt5::Widgets)
   ```

Comment: "Where am I missing out" - At least you are missing the **code** in the **question post** (not *linked*) and the log as a **text** (not *image*). And you have near 3k reputation..

Comment: Is there a specific *error* in the output? What else does it show?

Comment: there is no specific error in output...the output window shows "Starting ..." and the Mainwindow gui never shows up. However the same program runs fine with qmake and a .pro file. I am on Ubuntu 16.04